# \foreach with animation in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

I'm trying to modify the animation presented here [Example: Sine and Cosine functions animation](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/sine-and-cosine-functions-animation/) to include `phase`, so the rotation will start each time at different angle i.e, `phase =[0, 45 ,-45]` so I used foreach as below, the original animation is shown in [Example: Sine and Cosine functions animation](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/sine-and-cosine-functions-animation/), but the code didn't work *(please uncomment the related commands to animation to check the error I'm getting)*.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
%\newcounter{theangle}
%\setcounter{theangle}{0}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\angle{45};
        \fill[fill=red] (0,0) -- plot [domain=0:pi/180*\angle] (\x,{sin(\x r)}) -- (pi/180*\angle,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    %\begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first,controls]{40}
     %
     %\foreach \angle in {0,45,-45}
     %\whiledo{\angle<359}{

    \foreach \angle in {0,10,...,360}
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %\fill[blue!50] (-1,0) arc (0:\angle:1) -- (-2,0) -- cycle;
        %\fill[blue!50] plot[smooth,domain=0:\angle] (pi/180*\x,{sin(\x)}) |- (0,0);
        \def\radangle{pi/180*\angle};

        \fill[blue!50] (-1,0) arc (0:\angle:1) -- (-2,0) -- cycle;
        %\fill[fill=red] (0,0) -- plot [domain=0:\radangle] (\x,{sin(\x r)}) -- (\radangle,0) -- cycle;
        
        \draw (-2,0) +(\angle:1) circle (2pt) -- (pi/180*\angle,{sin(\angle)}) circle (2pt);
        \draw (-3.5,0) -- (7,0);
        \foreach \deg in {90, 180, 270, 360}
            \draw (pi/180*\deg,2pt) -- (pi/180*\deg,-2pt) node[below] {$\deg^\circ$};
        \draw (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2);
        \foreach \y in {-1,-0.5,0.5,1}
        \draw (2pt,\y) -- (-2pt,\y) node[left] {$\y$};
        \draw plot[smooth,domain=0:360] (pi/180*\x,{sin(\x)});
        \draw (-2,0) circle (1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
            %
     %   \stepcounter{theangle}
     %    \ifthenelse{\theangle<359}{\newframe}{
     %            \end{animateinline}}
    }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: but it doesn't compile and thats the problem, there is an error

Comment: You have to delete already the `\ ` placed everywhere. Write `\documentclass[12pt] {article}` instead of `[\documentclass\[12pt\] {article}]` **etc**.

Comment: I updated the code, the one included provides a working code that generates the required frames, all what I want to do is to use these frames to generate animated photo using animate in Tikiz

Comment: Please edit your code and delete the code that is useless and leave only what is problematic as a comment.

Comment: @Diana You can post your questions [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex) and you can get your desired answer. marmot or samcarter or anyone can help you.

Comment: @user213378 Helping a user does not mean giving him a ready-made answer, but teaching him to correct his mistakes.

Comment: @AndréC :-), I think that `marmot or samcarter or anyone` can help him to correct his mistakes as him(her) answers in this site! :-)

Comment: @user213378 Nothing prevents them from doing it here.

Comment: @AndréC Yes, certainly **but** ...  :-))))

Comment: @user213378 But what?

Answer (score 4):

The example makes use of `\clist_map_inline:nn` from LaTeX3 instead of TikZ's `\foreach` to iterate over the comma-separated list of phase shifts. For some reason, `\foreach` does not work inside `animateinline`.

Some pauses (`\newframe*`) are placed at suitable animation points; click the play button or the animation widget in order to continue:

[image]

(A Chromium-based browser is recommended for viewing the SVG version, as Firefox is a bit slow.)

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,animate}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\clistMap\clist_map_inline:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\drawit}[2]{% #1 angle (0<=#1<=360)
  \begin{tikzpicture}   % #2 phase shift

  \pgfmathsetmacro\angleRad{pi/180*(#1+#2)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angleDeg{#1+#2}

  \pgfmathsetmacro\unshiftedRad{pi/180*(#1)}

  \fill[blue!50] (-2,0) -- ++(#2:1) arc (#2:\angleDeg:1) -- cycle;
  
  \draw (-2,0) +(\angleDeg:1) circle (2pt) -- (\unshiftedRad,{sin(\angleDeg)}) circle (2pt);
  \draw (-3.5,0) -- (7,0);
  \foreach \deg in {90, 180, 270, 360}
      \draw (pi/180*\deg,2pt) -- (pi/180*\deg,-2pt) node[below] {$\deg^\circ$};
  \draw (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2);
  \foreach \y in {-1,-0.5,0.5,1}
  \draw (2pt,\y) -- (-2pt,\y) node[left] {$\y$};
    \draw plot[smooth,domain=0:360] (pi/180*\x,{sin(\x+#2)});
  \draw (-2,0) circle (1);
  \node [anchor=north east] at (current bounding box.north east) {$\varphi=#2^\circ$};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls]{30}
  \clistMap{0,45,-45}{%
    \drawit{0}{#1}
    \newframe*
    \multiframe{360}{i=1+1}{\drawit{\i}{#1}}%
    \ifthenelse{#1=-45}{}{\newframe*}%
  }  
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```